# How to mention multiple folder name in config.json in Cloud Functions

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I am using Cloud Functions to trigger DAG whenever file is placed in the GCP storage bucket eg: 
"folder_name":["Ad/pic/"].

```
{
"PROJECT_ID":"dev1",
"CLIENT_ID":"urlscjtk.apps.googleusercontent.com",
"WEBSERVER_ID":"323-tp",
"DAG_NAME":["composer_sample_simple_greeting"],
"folder_name":["Ad/pic/"],
"file_format":".csv",
"SERVICE_ACCOUNT":"dev@dev.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

It is working for single folder. I want this Cloud function should trigger DAG when file is placed in the multiple folder also but it is not happening, i have tried below options but doesn't work

```
{
"PROJECT_ID":"dev1",
"CLIENT_ID":"urlscjtk.apps.googleusercontent.com",
"WEBSERVER_ID":"323-tp",
"DAG_NAME":["composer_sample_simple_greeting"],
"folder_name":["Ad/pic/","Hit/learn/"],
"file_format":".csv",
"SERVICE_ACCOUNT":"dev@dev.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}


{
"PROJECT_ID":"dev1",
"CLIENT_ID":"urlscjtk.apps.googleusercontent.com",
"WEBSERVER_ID":"323-tp",
"DAG_NAME":["composer_sample_simple_greeting"],
"folder_name":["Ad/pic/"],
"folder_name":["Hit/learn/"]
"file_format":".csv",
"SERVICE_ACCOUNT":"dev@dev.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

Please help me how to configure multiple GCP bucket folder so that whenever file is placed in those folders my dag should be triggered.

Thanks

Comment: Where are you putting this file?

Comment: In GCP Cloud Storage

Comment: Can you provide your DAG? Something should be wrong in it for not accepting an array.